# OpenJDK 1.6 and SecureRandom/KeyGenerator (what is available?)

Tags: java, cryptography, key-generator

All of the following result in `"java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA  not SecureRandom available"` (or similar).

```
SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA256");
SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA-256");
SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1");
SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA-1");
SecureRandom prng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA");
```

Similar for the following (`"java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA KeyGenerator not available"`):

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("SHA256");
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("SHA-256");
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("SHA1");
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("SHA-1");
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("SHA");
```

What generators are available in OpenJDK? According to [Standard Algorithm Names](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#AppA), it looks like the SHA family should be available (at least for SecureRandom).

Sorry for the lame Java question. I'm a Crypto++ and OpenSSL kind of guy, and Google is returning a lot of noise. I'm working in Eclipse if it matters.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyGenerator has [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html). SHA* is a hash, not an encryption algorihtm. Using SHA* in the context of KeyGenerator makes little to no sense.

For SecureRandom (which, by the way, also has [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)) you are better off not specifying an algorithm unless you have specific requirements and you know what you are doing (like you know the provider you are trying to use)

The only connection I can come up with is the fact that the Sun JCE SecureRandom actually uses SHA1PRNG underneath.

Comment: "Using SHA* in the context of KeyGenerator makes little to no sense" - perhaps I'm disconnected (most likely). I want to generate a pseudo random stream using SHA-256, stuff the generated bytes in a Key, and later use the Key in a Cipher. There's not much to it.

Comment: "Sun JCE SecureRandom actually uses SHA1PRNG" - interesting, since its not listed under Java's JCE Standard Algorithm Names (a reference is now available).

Comment: The SecureRandom present in standard Java does SHA1 based random only. So if you want to instantiate a key object based on bytes from some other random source (like IAIK JCE which does different hashes) just fetch the bytes and initiate the key you want (AES etc)

Comment: Anything for SHA3 keccak?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help you

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/ListAllProviderAndItsAlgorithms.htm

Check it. Best of luck!

Comment: OK, thanks. SHA-256 is now required by, for example NIST, NESSIE, and ECRYPT (some hand waiving, SHA-1 is still OK for key derivation). I don't understand why one must jump through hoops for a required algorithm (its not like I'm asking for Skein or SHA-3 candidates).